# how to solve update query error

Tags: php, mysql

My error is

> Error while updating: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Kindly note down no error in speeling no error in post I checked every bit.. updation query is causing that error. I tried many times but didn't resolved. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

include('db.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname'], $con1);
        $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname'], $con1);
        $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone'], $con1);
        $zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip'], $con1);
        $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city'], $con1);
        $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country'], $con1);
        $userId = $_SESSION['userID'];

        $strSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sarah_cloudRecord.user_info WHERE userId = '$userId'" , $con1);

        //$Results = mysql_fetch_array($strSQL);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($strSQL);

    if($numrows != 0)
    {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($strSQL))
        {

        $dblname = $row['lastName'];
        $dbfname = $row['firstName'];
        $dbphone = $row['phone'];
            $dbzip = $row['zipCode'];
            $dbcity = $row['city'];
            $dbcountry = $row['country'];



        if ($fname != $dbfname || $fname == $dbfname) 
        {
            $newfName = $fname;
        }

        if ($lname != $dblname || $lname == $dblname) 
        {
            $newlName = $lname;
        }

        if ($phone != $dbphone || $phone == $dbphone) 
        {
            $newPhone = $phone;
        }

        if ($zip != $dbzip || $zip == $dbzip) 
        {
            $newZip = $zip;
        }

        if ($city != $dbcity || $city == $dbcity) 
        {
            $newCity = $city;
        }

        if ($country != $dbcountry || $country == $dbcountry) 
        {
            $newCountry = $country;
        }

        }

    $updateSQL = mysql_query("UPDATE sarah_cloudRecord.user_info SET firstName = '$newfName', lastName = '$newlName', phone = '$newPhone', city = '$newCity', zipCode = '$newZip', country = '$newCountry' WHERE userId = '$userId'", $con1);

        if (mysql_query($updateSQL, $con1)) 
        {
                echo "Update Successfully!";
        }
            else {
            echo "Error while updating: " . mysql_error($con1);
        }

    }

    else {

    echo "no records found";

    }

    }


        else
        {
            ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "http://dev.metawarez.com/cloud/login.php";
        </script>
    <?php
        }        

    ?>
```

Comment: You are using `mysql_query` twice

Comment: where is the **1** coming from?

Comment: @bub one is the result in $updateSQL

Comment: @Apb can't we use query twice?

Comment: NO. Why you want to do so? Once query is fired why you want to do it again? From your code `$updateSQL` variable contain 1 value as a result of `mysql_query(....)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read up about the situation that ***MySQL is deprecated and continuing to use it is strongly discouraged*** . There are lots of topics on Stack Overflow about easily and seemlessly transferring over to `MySQLi` or `PDO` . If you are a student you really, really should inform your tutors that the technology they are teaching with is deprecated - it's like taking a driving test in a Ford Pinto.

Comment: @Martin sometimes we make error by chance! it dosent mean to invole tutors. always encourage other if you have a better knowledge. and do you know i study by my own. everyone makes mistakes when you where student you do the same! lol encourage other.

Comment: I'm not blaming you at all, I don't mean to come across as blaming, but the change is a big change in PHP and a fairly fundamental change and it can and does really revolutionise the way the code is structured and reads. I'm also not associating your error relating to this question with your use of `MySQL_`. Just curious that there's been a big shift in the way the language runs in the last ~6 years (or more) and yet many many people still seem to be unaware of the change. . .

Comment: Try something like this, although there are many similar ones... it is well worth it... http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mysql_query` two time. You change your update query to

```
$updateSQL = "UPDATE sarah_cloudRecord.user_info SET firstName = '$newfName', lastName = '$newlName', phone = '$newPhone', city = '$newCity', zipCode = '$newZip', country = '$newCountry' WHERE userId = '$userId'";

if (mysql_query($updateSQL, $con1))
```

> Note:- mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or pdo

Comment: OMG! What i was doing.. i done like a blind... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the reply from the UPDATE, thats where the 1 comes from.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php

```
$updateSQL = mysql_query("UPDATE sarah_cloudRecord.user_info SET firstName = '$newfName', lastName = '$newlName', phone = '$newPhone', city = '$newCity', zipCode = '$newZip', country = '$newCountry' WHERE userId = '$userId'", $con1);

if ($updateSQL !== false) 
{
    echo "Update Successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Error while updating: " . mysql_error($con1);
}
```